# How can I backup a Veracrypt file container?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, backup, rsync, veracrypt

I have got a Veracrypt file that is approximately 100GB on an external hard drive. I make changes to the contents of this container often, and would like to know a way to quickly back up the updated file to a second external hard drive.

I am aware I can copy the file directly to the second drive after I am done working with it, but it will take a while since it is large. Is there a way to update changed portions of the file with rsync, for example? I understand the file is encrypted, which isn't very useful considering the methods used for comparison when copying.

How else can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I do the same with even larger file containers, and although I make a complete copy every few months, here's what I do weekly or so.

I have another identical container and open both at once, and simply copy, choosing the "overwrite older files" option.

That's the simplest way to do it. You might want to use a (backup) program with a "replicate file & folder deletions" option.

You might also want to make only incremental backups, although I personally find that to be too messy.

There is no magic bullet, alas, the answer is only that with both drives mounted you can treat them as normal drives and mirror/synchronize them.

If you are looking for good software to do so quickly, please ask us on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Sorry again that there's no magic trick, but I suspect that's what you expected to hear.

Answer (score 0):

Open the volume. Go to Settings...Preferences.
Look for:  Windows...'Preserve modification timestamp of file containers'.
Uncheck the box.

When you make a change to the volume contents and exit VeraCrypt the timestamp of the volume file will reflect the most recent changes.